# How do I correctly use colormaps (matplotlib) for discrete classes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pca, colormap

Y is a matrix. This is being plotted on a scatter plot.

```
Y = [[x1, y1],
     [x2, y2],
     ...
    ]
```

`y` is a list the classes for each variable in Y.

`classes` is a list of strings of all of the classes

Right now, I am plotting this like this:

```
cs = []
cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap_name)

for c in y:
    for i, l in enumerate(classes):
        if(str(c) == str(l)):
            cs.append(i)
            break;
plt.scatter(Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1])
```

I am also setting up a legend like this:

```
legend_handles = []
for i,l in enumerate(classes):
    patch = mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(i/len(classes)), label=l)
    legend_handles.append(patch)
plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, prop={'size':10})
```

However, the legend isn't wokring correctly. How do I correctly setup this with a legend?

Comment: You can add a `label` for `pyplot.scatter` right away: `plt.scatter(..., label=...)`, you just need to select those values which correspond to the class in question (i.e. know the indices which correspond to a class and then do `Y[indices, 0]`).

Comment: Thanks. worked perfectly.